# React Fetch Google API

Tags: reactjs, google-api

When ever I fetch this google API its giving me this error message within the console log what am I doing wrong?

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost/:1 Fetch API cannot load https://googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry%20potter. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
Code~

   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, InputGroup, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Global extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            query: ''
        }
    }

search() {
    const BASE_URL = 'https://googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}${this.state.query}`, { 
      method: 'GET',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}
render() {
    return(
        <div className="Global">
            <h2> Book Explorer!</h2>
            <FormGroup>
                <InputGroup>
                    <FormControl
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Search for a book"
                      onChange={event => this.setState({query: event.target.value})}
                      onKeyPress={event => {
                        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                            this.search();
                        }
                      }}
                      />
                      <InputGroup.Addon onClick={() => this.search()}>
                      <Glyphicon glyph="search"></Glyphicon>
                      </InputGroup.Addon>
                      </InputGroup>
                      </FormGroup>
                     </div>


)
}
}



export default Global;
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED VERSION:**

This is an issue with CORS, so you may consider setting more headers' params in the `fetch`:

```
search() {
    const BASE_URL = 'https://googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}${this.state.query}`, { 
      method: 'GET',
      headers:{
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, GET'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

=================

You forgot binding your `search()` function into the component, so just add it into your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        query: ''
    }
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
}
```

**OR**: Revising `search()` to be auto-bound:

```
search = () => {
  // copy your whole logics here
}
```

After that, `${BASE_URL}${this.state.query}` will return the correct value

Comment: So I added the this.search = this.search.bind(this); into the const identical to what you have posed but I am still getting this message. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2bundle.js:37487 GET https://googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=hi 404 ()

Comment: How about the API url, which returns it self an 404: https://googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry%20potter I tried and it is not found !!

Comment: Hey Thinh in the original post that was what I had in my search bar. So just a better understanding is I am building an application that is based off the google books api. Where when you enter in a book name in the search bar it will return back some strings or values from the google API. The only reason why the harry potter says 404 not found is I am unsure if my const url or if I have something incorrect or what I did wrong.

Comment: I just added a fix for CORS above, would you mind trying that again, thanks

Comment: Tried the above but I still get the same message I am thinking maybe it has something to do with my permissions from local host 3000. I really don't know. I really appreciate the help though thinh.

Comment: Oh really..doesn't work yet? How about adding more to headers, please see my newer version above ^^

Comment: Yeah I used the new version you have above ill copy and paste my entire code set with your new code added.

Comment: Sorry, newer version appears now !      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, GET'

Comment: Sorry again, just added "headers:{", please consider trying once again haha, thanks